# Compare two lists of distances (floats) in python

Tags: algorithm, list, math, floating-point, robotics

I'm looking to compare two lists of distances (floats) in python. The distances represent how far away my robot is from a wall at different angles. One array is my "best guess" distance array and the other is the array of actual distances. I need to return a number between [0, 1] that represents the similarity between these two lists of floats. The distances match up 1 to 1. That is, the distance at index 0 should be compared to the distance at index 0 in the other array. Right now, for each index, I am dividing the smaller number by the larger number to get a percentage difference. Then I am taking the average of these percentage differences (total percentage difference / number of entries in the array) to get a number between 0 and 1. However, my approach does not seem to be accurate enough. Is there a better algorithm for comparing two ordered lists of floats?

Comment: There isn't much to go on. There are all sorts of ways to compare two vectors for similarity. Some are good for some things, others for other things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you need a normalized Euclidean distance between two vectors.

[image]

It is simple to caclulate and you can read more about it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahalanobis_distance).